# How do I get DateTime::Format::Strptime to parse the date/times of leap seconds?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use `DateTime::Format::Strptime` to parse some date/times, and I can't seem to get it to parse the date/time for leap seconds (e.g., 2012-06-30T23:59:60UTC). The documentation says it supports up to 60 seconds for leap seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $utc = DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => 'Etc/UTC');

my $ymdhms_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%F %T',
                                                    locale => 'en_US',
                                                    time_zone => $utc,
                                                    strict => 1,
                                                    on_error => 'croak');

my $date = '2012-06-30 23:59:60';
print "date: $date\n";
my $dt = $ymdhms_parser->parse_datetime($date);
print "dt: $dt\n";
print "tz: ",$dt->time_zone,"\n";
```

The output I get is:

```
date: 2012-06-30 23:59:60
Parsed values did not produce a valid date at /path/to/test.pl line 14.
```

Versions:

```
DateTime 1.52
DateTime::LeapSecond 1.52
DateTime::Format::Strptime 1.77
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works as intended:

```
my $dt = DateTime->new(
   year      => 2012,
   month     =>    6,
   day       =>   30,
   hour      =>   23,
   minute    =>   59,
   second    =>   60,
   time_zone => $utc,
);
```

However, the call to `parse_datetime` is effectively doing the following:

```
my $dt = DateTime->new(
   year      => 2012,
   month     =>    6,
   day       =>   30,
   hour      =>   23,
   minute    =>   59,
   second    =>   60,
   time_zone => 'floating',
);

$dt->set_time_zone($utc);
```

The above results in `DateTime->new` to throwing an exception, which results in the error message received.

But I can't fault DateTime::Format::Strptime.

The time zone found in the string being parsed (e.g. if `%z` is being used) is passed to `->new`, and the time zone passed to the constructor is passed to `->set_time zone`. This allows for time zone conversions to happen when the time zone is specified in both places.

For example, say the input is `2020-03-25T00:00:00-05:00` (note the offset). And say you passed a `time_zone => 'UTC'` and an appropriate pattern to the constructor. The resulting DateTime object would be for 5am UTC instead of midnight UTC-05:00. This is good.

---

It's interesting that it is possible to create DateTime objects using the floating time zone with `60` for seconds.

```
$ perl -MDateTime -e'
   CORE::say
      DateTime
         ->new(
            year      => 2012,
            month     =>    6,
            day       =>   30,
            hour      =>   23,
            minute    =>   59,
            second    =>   60,
            time_zone => "UTC",
         )
            ->set_time_zone("floating");
'
2012-06-30T23:59:60
```

But DateTime is inconsistent about allowing it.

```
$ perl -MDateTime -e'
   CORE::say
      DateTime
         ->new(
            year      => 2012,
            month     =>    6,
            day       =>   30,
            hour      =>   23,
            minute    =>   59,
            second    =>   60,
            time_zone => "floating",
         );
'
Invalid second value (60)
 at -e line 1.
```

[Bug ticket filed.](https://github.com/houseabsolute/DateTime.pm/issues/103)

---

As a workaround, include the time zone in the data being parsed.

```
my $ymdhms_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%F %T%z',
   locale   => 'en_US',
   strict   => 1,
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $ymdhms_parser->parse_datetime($date.'Z');
```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround! It works! So is `DateTime::Format::Strptime` just not passing the `time_zone` argument I'm providing to `DateTime->new`? That means like a bug to me, or am I off-base?

Comment: Converting to UTC after the dt is constructed is a good thing. Say the input is `2020-03-25T00:00:00-05:00` (note the offset). Say you passed a `time_zone => 'UTC'` and an appropriate pattern to the constructor. The resulting dt would be for 5am UTC instead of midnight UTC-05:00. This is good. This is already mentioned in the answer.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks.