# Convert the given time to site specific time in Perl

Tags: datetime, perl, timezone

I have written a script which converts the given time to site specific time.
I have two sites (ex. London and Bangalore - VM's).

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Parse;
use DateTime;
use Date::Format;
use Time::Local;

my $id = "BAN";

my %time_zone_hash = (
        'LON' => 'Europe/London',
        'BAN' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
);

my $bang_time = convertSiteSpecificTime($id, "2023-05-15 04:30:00");
print "time:$bang_time\n";

print "time in readable format:".localtime($bang_time)."\n";

sub convertSiteSpecificTime {
        my $id = shift;
        my $time_str = shift;
        my $epoch_time = str2time(time2str("%Y-%m-%d %T", str2time($time_str)));

        if (!$epoch_time) {
                print "'$time_str' is not a valid date. Please provide a valid date.\n";
                exit(1);
        }
        my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $epoch_time);
        $dt->set_time_zone($time_zone_hash{$id});

        print "dt: $dt\n";
        return $dt->epoch();
}
```

Current Result:

```
dt: 2023-05-15T09:00:00
time:1684121400
time in readable format:Mon May 15 04:30:00 2023
```

Expected Result:

```
dt: 2023-05-15T09:00:00
time:1684121400
time in readable format:Mon May 15 09:00:00 2023
```

So, currently I'm in London VM and running this script. So the time (`2023-05-15 04:30:00`) should be converted to Bangalore specific time since I have initialized `$id` value as `BAN`.

The result in line `print "time:$bang_time\n";` prints right unixtime. i.e., `1684121400`. But the human readable format time in line `print "time in readable format:".localtime($bang_time)."\n";`  is printing not as expected. The problem here is I'm using `localtime` during time conversion.

Is there any way where I can get the desired result as mentioned in the Expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were to boil down your question to what I think you are asking, it's

> How do I get `localtime` to use `Asia/Kolkata`?

It uses the `TZ` env var.

```perl
for my $tz (qw(
   UTC
   Europe/London
   Asia/Kolkata
   America/Halifax
)) {
   local $ENV{ TZ } = $tz;
   say sprintf "%-16s %s", "$tz:", "".localtime( 1684121400 );
}
```

```
UTC:             Mon May 15 03:30:00 2023
Europe/London:   Mon May 15 04:30:00 2023
Asia/Kolkata:    Mon May 15 09:00:00 2023
America/Halifax: Mon May 15 00:30:00 2023
```

---

Since you're already using DateTime, let me present you with a cleaner solution.

```perl
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => "%F %T",
   strict    => 1,
   time_zone => "Europe/London",
   on_error  => "croak",
);

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime( "2023-05-15 04:30:00" );
say $dt->epoch();
say $dt->strftime( "%FT%T%z" );

$dt->set_time_zone( "Asia/Kolkata" );
say $dt->epoch();
say $dt->strftime( "%FT%T%z" );
```

```
1684121400
2023-05-15T04:30:00+0100
1684121400
2023-05-15T09:00:00+0530
```

---

Once more, using Time::Piece. It's much lighter than DateTime, but it's a lot tricker to use.

```perl
use Time::Piece qw( localtime );

my $dt;

{
   local $ENV{ TZ } = "Europe/London";
   $dt = localtime->strptime( "2023-05-15 04:30:00", "%F %T" );
   say $dt->epoch();
   say $dt->strftime( "%FT%T%z" );
}

{
   local $ENV{ TZ } = "Asia/Kolkata";
   say $dt->epoch();
   say $dt->strftime( "%FT%T%z" );
}
```

```
1684121400
2023-05-15T04:30:00+0100
1684121400
2023-05-15T09:00:00+0530
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the above code using `DateTime::Format::Strptime`'s `parse_datetime` method will fail if the value being parsed is a valid leap second, as you may recall from your own answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60839787/5153779.